# PHP Multi Curl curl_multi_select slowing down the Process. Another option works much faster but with flaws?

Tags: php, curl

Alright, I didn't know how to word the question very well. But I'm trying as hard as I can to get a multi curl script to work as fast as possible. My first attempt is just straight from the PHP documentation...

```
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($this->multi_handle, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($this->multi_handle) != -1) {
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($this->multi_handle, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    }
    else
        return;
}
```

This is incredibly slow. For 100 entries, it takes about 30 seconds. At first I thought there was nothing that can be done, but then I tried this solution I found on the Internet...

```
  while (($execrun = curl_multi_exec($this->multi_handle, $running)) ==                           CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM) {
    ;
  }
  if ($execrun != CURLM_OK) {
    break;
  }
```

And this shocked me because, when I run 100 urls, it takes less than 5 seconds and all the data is stored in the db like planned. The problem though, is if I run 500 urls through this, it starts missing some data or duplicating data from the urls. It still finishes incredibly fast, but I can't have a script that's missing information. I've searched for weeks on this issue. I have PHP 5.5. I just can't get a solution to have it work as fast as the second solution, but not skip any data like the first solution. And I've searched my script in and out and it literally comes down to this block of code. Curl_multi_select just loops and takes each entry individually before it starts the next. The second solution is the speed I want but not the reliability.

Here are the options I'm using. They are in lowercase but get added to the setopt_array correctly.

```
        ,'returntransfer'   => 1
        ,'followlocation'   => 1
        ,'maxredirs'        => 10
        ,'header'           => 0
        ,'post'             => false
        ,'timeout'          => 10
        ,'connecttimeout'   => 5
        ,'ipresolve'        => 'CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4'
        ,'httpheader'       => null
        ,'useragent'        => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
        ,'encoding'         => ''
        ,'ssl_verifypeer'   => false
        ,'ssl_verifyhost'   => false
```

If there's any advice or help you can give me to either speed up curl_mutli_select or make the second option capture skipped urls or duplicated urls, that would be awesome. I can provide other information on request. Thanks in advance.

So another big question is, what is going on in the 2nd script that allows it to work so fast. Obviously there is a way to have a multi curl script that can be incredibly fast, since it can go through 100 urls, get the content, parse the content, store the data in a table very quickly. The php documentation version just gets boggled down by curl_multi_select but that seems to be a key in making sure every single request gets processed. Somehow the second version is skipping some requests or duplicating requests.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found a bandaid solution that works on the second example... and every url gets used. I have a class that keeps requests in an array. So what I did was this...

```
        // Now grab the information about the completed requests
    while ($info = curl_multi_info_read($this->multi_handle)) {
        //
        // tons of stuff here that is not relevant to the fix

        if(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) == 200)
        {
            call_user_func($callback, $content, $url, $ch, $user_data, $user_data);

            unset($this->outstanding_requests[$ch_array_key]);

            curl_multi_remove_handle($this->multi_handle, $ch);
        }
        else
        {
            //unset the outstanding request so it doesn't get stuck in a loop
            unset($this->outstanding_requests[$ch_array_key]);

            //these come back as 0's, so not found. Restart the request
            self::startRequest($url);   
        }
    }
```

So the solution was to find any entry that came back as HTTP:0 and then just restart its request. Only problem I'm having now, is this is slowing it up a little. I can get 100 requests done in less than 7 seconds, but when I try 500 or 1000, it progressively gets slower. Going to figure out what is causing that. If you have any tips, let me know. I keep track of memory usage and memory doesn't seem to be the problem unless I'm missing something within the loops.